# Rails admin gem co-related dropdown is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin gem for my application, i have 2 models state and substate, State has many sub state and substate belongs to particular state, for this i need co-related dropdown.

I have tried this method, But I'm confused where to add this code.

```
config.model State do
  field :sub_states do
    associated_collection_cache_all false  
    associated_collection_scope do
      obj_data = bindings[:object]
      Proc.new { |scope|
        by position
      scope = scope.where(state_id: team.state_id) if obj_data.present?
      scope = scope.limit(30) # 'order' does not work here
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean corelated? you want one dropdown to change in real-time when the other changes?

Comment: yes, based on the first dropdown second dropdown should change

Comment: Rails admin does not have a way to do this builtin, You will need to create your own custom field where you would render both dropdowns. For an example of how this would work checkout this patch to rails admin that does just that so polymorphic fields let you choose the type first and then the records for that type are loaded https://github.com/gotandem-io/rails_admin/commit/0ec67c412127b6f464f29211ecd9f74b3b7c8f83